# Converting Data Trigger XAML to C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin

```
<Image Width="16">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources/image1.png"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources/image2.png"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Referring to the XAML code above, I'm confused in how to convert it to XAML, for example the Data Trigger part, anyone has any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far, at which point you get stuck? Please, post some c# codes showing your effort

Comment: I only got the first 2 line, where you declare for the image properties,
I'm stucked at the <Style TargetType = "{x:Type Image}"> and how to link Data Trigger to The Style in image part, usually I just declare data trigger externally like 
var imageDataTrigger = new Data Trigger();
imageDataTrigger.Value = false ... and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After little refactor, I think u need this:

```
Style style = new Style(typeof(Image));

// Style Setter to handle 'false' case
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Image.SourceProperty, new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/image2.png", UriKind.Relative))));

// DataTrigger to handle 'true' case
DataTrigger dataTrigger = new DataTrigger();
dataTrigger.Binding = new Binding("Value");
dataTrigger.Value = true;
dataTrigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(Image.SourceProperty, new BitmapImage(new Uri("Resources/image1.png", UriKind.Relative))));
style.Triggers.Add(dataTrigger);

this.image.Style = style;
```

Comment: don't forget to accept my answer if it is working as you expected (I don't like to find already answered post during data mining ;) )

Comment: Okay sure, thanks for the guide! Still a newbie here! ><